# Postgres function to update old data and insert new data

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to write a function that when my script pulls information from AD that it inserts new entries that don't exist and then update the ones that do exist. New entries will have an id that comes from a sequence.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SCHEMA".fn_name()
    returns trigger AS 
$$
    begin
        if new.dn_id is null then
            NEW.dn_id = nextval("SCHEMA".seq_name); 
        else if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then 
            insert into "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"(dn, dn_name, search, user_cat) values (new.dn, new.dn_name, 
              new.search, new.user_cat) where old.dn_name = new.dn_name;
    RETURN NEW;
    end;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';\

create trigger trg_name
before insert or update
on "SCHEMA"."TABLE"
for each row
execute procedure "SCHEMA".fn_name();
```

I am fairly new to postgresql. I know with oracle you can use reference NEW as new Old as old in the trigger as follows;

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_name
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON table
    REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT seq_name.NEXTVAL INTO :new.dn_id FROM DUAL;
END trg_name;
```

How do I get the same functionality I had in oracle in postgres with a function?

Answer (score 1):

## Merge

It seems that `MERGE` does not implemented in Postgres yet.

## Way 1 - `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`

Read more [here with theory & examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

This way requires constraint (`PRIMARY KEY` or any `UNIQUE` constraint) which name you know (not automatically generated). In example constaint called `pk_known_languages`.

```sql
INSERT INTO public.known_languages(id, "comment", translations)
 VALUES ('en', 'English', 'Translations here'),
         ('ru', 'Русский', 'Тут переводы')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pk_known_languages
  DO UPDATE
  SET "comment" = EXCLUDED."comment",
     translations = EXCLUDED.translations;
```

Note: to `DELETE` some records you need way 2.

## Way 2 - big query with `CTE`

**`CTE` - Common Table Expresson** - is regular SQL command (`SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` and even `VALUES`) executed before main SQL command to which it is attached. Read more [here with theory & examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Example of `CTE`:

```sql
    WITH cte_name AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM public.my_table_1
    )
    INSERT INTO public.my_table_2
    SELECT *
    FROM cte_name;
```

It is one big query, `cte_name`'s result acts as temp table which is available in main command.

**Solution for merge by the same `id`s:**

(This will update records with the same `id`'s and insert records with new or `NULL` `id`s.)

```sql
WITH data(id, "comment", translations) AS (
  VALUES ('en', 'English', 'Translations here'),
         ('ru', 'Русский', 'Тут переводы')
),
 upd AS (
   UPDATE public.known_languages
     SET
       "comment" = data."comment",
       translations = data.translations
     FROM data
     WHERE known_languages.id = data.id
     RETURNING data.id   -- return all mathced ids
 )
 INSERT INTO public.known_languages
   SELECT *
   FROM data
   WHERE data.id NOT IN (SELECT id
                         FROM upd);
```

Each next `CTE` can use data returned by all previous `CTE`s.
First `CTE`, `data`, returns the data you want to insert/update.
Second `CTE`, `upd`, does the update of rows with the same `id` and returns matched `id`s to ignore them on following insert.
Third, regular INSERT command using `upd`'s result to exclude such `id`s from `INSERT`.

**If all new records always have no id:**

(This variation is for speed-up only, you can still use previous query in this case.)

```sql
WITH data(id, "comment", translations) AS (
  VALUES (NULL, 'English', 'Translations here'),
         ('ru', 'Русский', 'Тут переводы')
),
 upd AS (
   UPDATE public.known_languages
     SET
       "comment" = data."comment",
       translations = data.translations
     FROM data
     WHERE known_languages.id = data.id
       AND data.id IS NOT NULL
 )
 INSERT INTO public.known_languages
   SELECT *
   FROM data
   WHERE data.id IS NULL;
```

**Note:**

This query can also be extended to `DELETE` records which does not present in `data` (or by any other condition). Just transform `INSERT` into third `CTE` and add `DELETE` statement as main command.